# JRebel: Not reloading spring controller @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, jrebel

I'm trying to figure out why JRebel doesnt reload @Controllers/ @RequestMappings. Whenever i change a requestmapping, or add a new one, JRebel does pick up the change:

JRebel: Reloading class 'apps.myapp.controllers.SomeController'.

But the change is not propagated to the JRebel Spring plugin.

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Could be bug in JRebel or some unknown configuration, which isn't supported right now. Please turn to support@zeroturnaround.com with the issue and send jrebel.log file after trying to reproduce the issue with logging on. Logging options are in your IDE plugin settings or can be turned on by JVM arguments http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/learn/sending-log/